# routesImport does not work in playframework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

it seems that routesImport does not work in playframework 2.0.2.
i put these in the Build.scala:

```
val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  routesImport += "controllers._"
)
```

this will work:

```
GET /    controllers.SiteApplication.home()
```

but this does not work:

```
GET /   SiteApplication.home()
```

reload command is executed after editing Build.scala.
any help? many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your methods need to be fully qualified.

They discuss this at the link below on their groups page.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/k5MT68xFzDA%5B1-25%5D